# set_post_thumbnail_size only working for width

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I want all my thumbnails to be the same size (220px by 130px).

I've tried both the code `set_post_thumbnail_size( 220, 130);` and 
`set_post_thumbnail_size( 220, 130, true);` in my functions.php file but the height of the image in my browser is 220px by 92px. 
Why is this and how can I get the image size I want?

In static sites I normally use object-fit: cover so that things are not stretched. Would be nice if Wordpress could do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This code will only work with images uploaded after it was implemented, for older images use a plugin like "thumbnail regenerate" to resize them.